# How to query search only for post titles?

Tags: php, wordpress

I tried this but I keep getting all posts

```
$post_ids_post = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare(
    "SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE post_title LIKE '%s'", 
    $search, $search 
));
$tit = array(
    'post__in' => $post_ids_post,
    's' => $s
);
```

I am sending a var via GET to the search result page, if the form had TITLE checked, means the user wants to only search the $term by title and nothing else, but the user could choose search by category, therefore i cannot override the whole query. I need a specific query for post titles only

Comment: @GufranHasan thing is i don't want to put it in function as that would override all the other queries. I am building an advanced search form, only missing ht "search by title" only

Comment: Okay edit your question now and explain your requirement.

Comment: @GufranHasan I did

Comment: see this link http://heycodetech.com/make-wordpress-search-only-in-post-title/

Comment: Have you considered using/extending the highly regarded Relevanssi plugin?

Comment: nope but I am trying this now `$posts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."posts WHERE post_title LIKE '%" . $_REQUEST['s'] ."%' AND post_status = 'publish' AND post_type = 'post'");` it works but i keep having all posts, even tho if I do print_r() i get always the correct one while I can see different posts tho

Answer (score 0):

You can get help from this link http://heycodetech.com/make-wordpress-search-only-in-post-title/

```
//put this code in the functions.php file.
    function title_filter( $where, &$wp_query )
    {
        global $wpdb;
        if ( $search_term = $wp_query->get( 'search_prod_title' ) ) {
            $where .= ' AND ' . $wpdb->posts . '.post_title LIKE \'%' . esc_sql( like_escape( $search_term ) ) . '%\'';
        }
        return $where;
    }
```

Comment: yeah but that will override the general query search, what if I want another query only for category afterwards?

Comment: okay got it, you want to create your custom search query right.

Comment: yeah, because I need a specific one only for titles

Comment: Have tried this https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11822/how-to-limit-search-to-post-titles?

Comment: how would I then use that in a query tho?